# My Storm Topology neither working(not generating output) nor failing (not generating errors or exceptions)

Tags: java, apache-storm

**I have a topology in which I am trying to count word occurrences which are being generated by SimulatorSpout (not real Stream) and after that write to MySQL database table, the table scheme is very simple:**

```
Field  |  Type        |  ...
ID     |  int(11)     |      Auto_icr
word   |  varchar(50) |  
count  |  int(11)     |
```

But I am facing weird problem(as I beforementioned)
I successfully submitted The Topology to my Storm Cluster which consists of 4 supervisors, and I can see the flow of the Topology in Storm Web UI 
(no exceptions) but when I checked the MySQL table, to my surprise, the table is empty...

ANY COMMENTS, SUGGESTIONS ARE WELCOME...

Here are spouts and bolts:

```
public class MySQLConnection {

    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.2:3306/test?";
    private static String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException  {

        Class.forName(dbClass);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "qwe123");            
        return conn;    
     }
}
```

============================= SentenceSpout ===============================

```
public class SentenceSpout extends BaseRichSpout{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private boolean _completed = false;

private SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
private String [] sentences = {
        "Obama delivered a powerfull speech against USA",
        "I like cold beverages",
        "RT http://www.turkeyairline.com Turkish Airlines has delayed some flights",
        "don't have a cow man...",
        "i don't think i like fleas"
    };

private int index = 0;


public void open (Map config, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
    _collector = collector;
}

public void nextTuple () {

        _collector.emit(new Values(sentences[index]));
        index++;
        if (index >= sentences.length) {
            index = 0;  

        Utils.waitForSeconds(1);
    }
}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("sentence"));
}

public void ack(Object msgId) {
    System.out.println("OK: " + msgId);
}   

public void close() {}

public void fail(Object msgId) {
    System.out.println("FAIL: " + msgId);
    }
}
```

============================ SplitSentenceBolt ==============================

```
public class SplitSentenceBolt extends BaseRichBolt {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private OutputCollector _collector;

public void prepare (Map config, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
    _collector = collector;
}

public void execute (Tuple tuple) {

    String sentence = tuple.getStringByField("sentence");
    String httpRegex = "((https?|ftp|telnet|gopher|file)):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*";
    sentence = sentence.replaceAll(httpRegex, "").replaceAll("RT", "").replaceAll("[.|,]", "");
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    for (String word : words) {
        if (!word.isEmpty())
        _collector.emit(new Values(word.trim()));
    }
    _collector.ack(tuple);
}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
   }
 }
```

=========================== WordCountBolt =================================

```
public class WordCountBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private HashMap<String , Integer> counts = null;
private OutputCollector _collector; 
private ResultSet resSet = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
private Connection _conn = null;

private String path = "/home/hduser/logOfStormTops/logger.txt";
String rLine = null;

public void prepare (Map config, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
    counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    _collector = collector;
}

public void execute (Tuple tuple) {

    int insertResult = 0;
    int updateResult = 0;

    String word = tuple.getStringByField("word");
    //----------------------------------------------------
    if (!counts.containsKey(word)) {            

        counts.put(word, 1);
        try {
            insertResult = wordInsertIfNoExist(word);
            if (insertResult == 1) {
                _collector.ack(tuple);
            } else {
                _collector.fail(tuple);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  else {
    //-----------------------------------------------
        counts.put(word, counts.get(word) + 1);

        try {
            // writing to db
            updateResult = updateCountOfExistingWord(word);
            if (updateResult == 1) {
                _collector.ack(tuple);
            } else {
                _collector.fail(tuple);
            }
            // Writing to file
            BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
            buffer.write("[ " + word + " : " + counts.get("word") + " ]");
            buffer.newLine();
            buffer.flush();
            buffer.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("{word-" + word + " : count-" + counts.get(word) + "}");
    }

}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
}

// *****************************************************

public int wordInsertIfNoExist(String word) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String query = "SELECT word FROM wordcount WHERE word=\"" + word + "\"";
    String insert = "INSERT INTO wordcount (word, count) VALUES (\"" + word +  "\", 1)";
    _conn = MySQLConnection.getConnection();
    stmt = _conn.createStatement();
    resSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    int res = 0;
    if (!resSet.next()) {

         res = stmt.executeUpdate(insert);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Yangi qiymatni kirityotrganda nimadir sodir bo'ldi");
    }
    resSet.close();
    stmt.close();
    _conn.close();
    return res;
}

public int updateCountOfExistingWord(String word) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String update = "UPDATE wordcount SET count=count+1 WHERE word=\"" + word + "\"";   
    _conn = MySQLConnection.getConnection();        
    stmt = _conn.createStatement();
    int result = stmt.executeUpdate(update);

        //System.out.println(word + "'s count has been updated (incremented)");

    resSet.close();
    stmt.close();
    _conn.close();
    return result;
    } 
  }
```

========================= WordCountTopology ==============================

```
public class WordCountTopology {
private static final String SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID = "sentence-spout";
private static final String SPLIT_BOLT_ID = "split-bolt";
private static final String COUNT_BOLT_ID = "count-bolt";
private static final String TOPOLOGY_NAME = "NewWordCountTopology";

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public static void main(String[] args) throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException {

SentenceSpout spout = new SentenceSpout();
SplitSentenceBolt splitBolt = new SplitSentenceBolt();
WordCountBolt countBolt = new WordCountBolt();

TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

builder.setSpout(SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID, spout, 2);

builder.setBolt(SPLIT_BOLT_ID, splitBolt, 4).shuffleGrouping(SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID);

builder.setBolt(COUNT_BOLT_ID, countBolt, 4).fieldsGrouping(SPLIT_BOLT_ID, new Fields("word"));

Config config = new Config();
config.setMaxSpoutPending(100);
config.setDebug(true);

StormSubmitter submitter = new StormSubmitter(); 

submitter.submitTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME, config, builder.createTopology());

   }
}
```

Comment: Check the logs to see if there are any exceptions thrown.  I'd also surround the execute() logic in your bolts with a try-catch block where the catch block writes a message to the log.

Comment: can you post the storm ui picture? $storm ui; then on your browser go to localhost:8080

Comment: we've seen this kind of problem with several versions of storm and it seems to be related to internal messaging. The latest versions with netty appear to particularly problematic and we are moving back to zmq. Which version are you using and what are the supervisor settings?

Comment: @bridiver I am using 0.9.3 version

Comment: sorry @SQL.injection I could not upload picture, Because I just started my profile, and it says I need at least 10 reputations:)

Comment: @ChrisGerken I checked the logs, but I could not find any exceptions thrown by Storm

Comment: In the Storm UI I can see that split-bolt is showing acked tuples, but in contrast, the count-bolt (main business logic)is showing neither acked nor failed, strange?

Comment: Can you give me some example usage of MySQL along with Storm, I would really appreciate

Comment: have you tried on local mode?

Comment: yuhhuu, it is working perfectly on local mode and writing to MySQL table, but I faced another strange situation, this time (LocalCluster mode) Storm UI is not showing anything about topology on the screen but I can see the topology running smoothly on command line, What is the ...... ,  why why why

Comment: if nobody explains it to me I really get mad, it took me so long causing me thinking where I am making mistake, but it turns out... why it is not working on Distributed Mode

Comment: I would try backing out to a pre-netty version. We've had a lot of problems with mysterious stoppages since upgrading and we are in the process of rolling those upgrades back. We had similar issues early on with zmq and they eventually got sorted out. It appears that netty may have some of the same problems.

Comment: so in this case, what do you suggest me, 'cause I should show demo to my Senior so that he can approve my thesis topic, I am going to build news recommendation service backed by Storm, but if cannot deal with this issue I cannot start my graduation work, hence, any advice suggestions tips references are highly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: well, the reason why i want your storm ui print is to make sure the tuples are failing in your mysql bolt and not somewhere else. It should be straightforward to implement a mysql bolt... hence my request for storm ui.

Comment: @SQL.injection they are neither failing nor succeeding, I checked UI over and over, no exception, but as above mentioned, the same topology is working perfectly in Local mode, so there should be someting with Storm's inter-node messaging responsible for this

Comment: does your mysql bold has  Acked and Executed tuples? are they in the same number as the tuples emited by the previous bolt?

Comment: btw chage your execute methood to something like this/or don't catch the exceptions at all (it allow you to see the exceptions directly on storm UI:         } catch (SQLException e) {          
            throw e();}

Comment: mysql bolt executed tuples, but not acked nor failed

Answer (score 0):

It is because the _collector.ack(tuple) is not being called when there is exception thrown. When there are too many pending tuple, spout will stop sending new tuples. Try throwing out RuntimeException instead of printStackTrace.