# How does Storm Topology works in distributed mode?

Tags: mysql, network-programming, real-time, apache-storm

Say, If I have a Nimbus node and four Supervisor nodes and I have a MySQL server running (bind address 0.0.0.0) on my Nimbus node, and my Topology consists of one spout for emitting sentences, one bolt for splitting those sentences and emitting words for another bolt which is responsible for updating these words in a MySQL database table... So how my bolt (database updater bolt) interact with MySQL if it is located in other nodes... The reason I am giving these question is that I have a topology as described above, and it is running perfectly and updating MySQL table in **Local Mode** but when I submitted it to the **Real Cluster (Distributed Mode)** with four supervisors I can see no update in MySQL table, but the topology is running without throwing no exceptions like network error or others, I also checked log files, no exceptions just info and some warn messages.
So I put topology in StackOverflow earlier but there is no sufficient answer, hence,I want to know how Storm's inter-node communication works (interacting with DB, File System, Network...)

Comment: I don't think that the problem is related to Storm. I guess, that your DB connection is not set-up correctly. Can you verify that the connection to the DB is opened correctly? Did you try to remote debug your bolt code? Can you verify, that your DB-Bolt is receiving tuples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378092/my-storm-topology-neither-workingnot-generating-output-nor-failing-not-genera?noredirect=1#comment50832219_31378092

Comment: you can see my topology from  this link

Comment: Connection is opened correctly, I checked the connection from other application, it is working, I can see DB bolt receiving tuples from the Storm UI, but DB bolt neither acked nor failed tuples which are being received

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, my question here is about how Storm works in distributed environment (interaction with DB, File System, Network ... ) in short, inter-node communication internals of Storm, If you have any knowledge on this please share it with, I would really appreciate it ...

Comment: In order to ack/fail tuples, you need to assign message IDs in your spout, and anchor output tuples to their input tuples in bolts. See https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Did you check my previous question, in which I presented all my Topology classes, the link is given above |

Comment: Yes. But in this question, you claim that do data is inserted into DB table. But in the comment above you say "but DB bolt neither acked nor failed tuples". Those are two different things.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, Can you clarify your statement I didn't catch clearly what you meant

Comment: In the other thread you claim "but when I checked the MySQL table, to my surprise, the table is empty". Here you say in the comment above " DB bolt neither acked nor failed tuples". Both things are not related to each other. Furthermore, your problem is most likely not related to "Storm's inter-node communication"...

Comment: I have the following theory: inserting data into DB fails in cluster due to wrong DB connection setup. However, your calls to `_collector.fail(tuple)` do not have any effect, because you did not assign message IDs to tuples in spout and do not anchor your tuples correctly in bolts. See https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html to get fault-tolerance setup right. Before that, you should put additional log statements into DB-Writing Bolt for insert-success and insert-fail case to see if inserting works or not.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, so you claim my DB setup was wrong, in this case, how can you explain that the exactly same configuration, the topology on the whole, worked perfectly in Local Mode?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax yes you are right, I forgot to assign msgID to tuples, but I was wondering, let's say I didn't use asking, anyway, I should see some exceptions in log files related to MySQL table, the point is here, I just want to know how Storm works in Distributed mode, that is all, so that I can see the whole picture, and make some modifications based on this, I know that my topology is missing something, if you are well familiar with Storm, Can you please tune my topology to Dist. Mode !!!